# Javascript wait for chrome xhr request to complete

Tags: javascript

Im trying to scrape some news articles on a webpage but I need to click through each page.

I wrote some code to do it but the problem is I have to wait for the XHR request to finish before extracting the new data.

The XHR request is generated after a click on the new page happens.

**In a pure chrome javascript, no selenium or nodejs, how can I wait for all chrome xhr requests to finish?**

```
// Keep track of how many pages were selected
var pagesScraped = 0;

// Gets the next page on the list of news articles.
function getNextPage() {
  var pagination = document.querySelectorAll('#pagination_top > div > ul > li > a');
  pagination[pagination.length-1].click();
  getNewsArticleTitles();
}

// Extracts the news article titles
function getNewsArticleTitles() {

  // Wait for network pending to complete?

  var articles = document.querySelectorAll('#hits > div > div > div > div > article > div.fxs_floatingMedia_textBody > h4 > a');
  for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i ++) {
    console.log(articles[i].innerHTML);
  }
  pagesScraped ++;
  if (pagesScraped < 68) {
    getNextPage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When scraping the web, I usually wait for some visible changes in the DOM and take that as an indicator that the page has loaded and proceed. If you want a pure js way, this is one way of doing it

```
function checkIfNewPageLoaded() {
   // you can update this method as needed
   var pageNo = document.querySelector("span.current_page_number");
   var success =  pageNo && Number(pageNo.innerText.trim()) > pagesScraped; // meaning wait for page number to incre
ment 
       return success;
    }

var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if (checkIfNewPageLoaded()) {
      console.log("Proceed with your execution of next page");
      clearInterval(checkExist);
      getNewsArticleTitles(); // get new articles now
   }
}, 500); // check every 500ms
```

If you instead want to wait until all ajax requests are finished in your document, no matter how many of them exist, I think you can use jquery's $.ajaxStop event this way:

```
 $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
      // 0 === $.active
  });
```

I haven't tested the ajaxStop myself but it's known to work. But I can't think of any scenario where my first solution wouldn't work